# Chrome locks up when uploading images

Tags: release-loki, google-chrome

My Google Chrome-browser suddenly locks up every time i try to upload any image. I've tryed uploading to canvas, facebook etc, but every time the image is done uploading, the browser locks up, and i have to reboot. Any ideas?

Comment: Files 0.3.5 update fixed this issue. Thank you. > Same problem here with upgrade to new Chrome 59. Chrome 58 upload form
> is ok. Please fix this ASAP. For now i've downgraded to Chrome 58
> (download
> `https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_58.0.3029.110-1_amd64.deb`
> then `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_58.0.3029.110-1_amd64.deb`)

Comment: Oh, it's not only images. I tryed uploading a pdf to an e-mail, and it locked up again...

Comment: Any from using file browser will lock up your browser. You can open another windows and use any file upload and it will lock the current windows and unlock the previous

Comment: Is there any way to update to the Files 0.3.5 on Freya?

Comment: How is it fixed? Did you do anything besides update/upgrade? I still got this annoying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fixed now. Problably an update...

Comment: did you do anything?

Comment: Don't remember. I think an update fixed it...

Answer (score 2):

Please look at:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=716892#c5

This issue concerns any file selection dialog.

Comment: confirm this solved the issue for me