# Google Chrome Browser loses input when Pantheon File Browser is invoked for file upload

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, google-chrome

On Loki 0.4.1, when using the latest Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit), when trying to upload a file to a web page with the invoked Pantheon File Browser, somehow Chrome loses all inputs until Chrome is restarted completely.

If the page accepts drag and drop, it'll work just fine as a work around.

Any idea as to what's going on here?

Comment: same issue https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/12308/chrome-locks-up-when-uploading-images

Comment: Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)
pantheon-files 0.3.5 still have this problem

Answer (score 1):

So I just had a Files and OS update get pushed, and suddenly this is no longer an issue. That was fast! Very awesome... so far I've been loving Elementary OS!

Answer (score 1):

Files 0.3.5 update fixed this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bug fix found. it is caused by the 'GTK_MODULES=pantheon-filechooser-module' env. After removing it from /etc/profile.d/pantheon-filechooser-module.sh and reboot, Chrome does not freeze when uploading a file anymore.
 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=716892

Answer (score -1):

If someone still have this problem - simply delete this file: pantheon-filechooser-module.sh in /etc/profile.d/ and reboot